# Magento REST API: What populates the api2_acl_attribute Table?

Tags: api, oauth, rest-api

I'm trying to run through the [oAuth/REST examples](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-OverallCapabilities) on the Magento website and I'm hitting a snag.

I've successfully created a consumer key and a consumer secret, and used these to fetch an authentication token.  However, my API request

```
$resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
$productData = json_encode(array(
    'type_id'           => 'simple',
    'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
    'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
    'weight'            => 1,
    'status'            => 1,
    'visibility'        => 4,
    'name'              => 'Simple Product',
    'description'       => 'Simple Description',
    'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
    'price'             => 99.95,
    'tax_class_id'      => 0,
));
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
```

Keeps returning the following error

> Invalid auth/bad request (got a 400, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
>   {"messages":{"error":[{"code":400,"message":"The request data is invalid."}]}}

I've traced the failure to the following point.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php
if ($this->getRequest()->isAssocArrayInRequestBody()) {
    $this->_errorIfMethodNotExist('_create');                    
    $filteredData = $this->getFilter()->in($requestData);
    if (empty($filteredData)) {
        $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_REQUEST_DATA_INVALID);
    }
    $newItemLocation = $this->_create($filteredData);
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Location', $newItemLocation);
}
```

Specifically, `$filteredData` is coming back as an empty array.  This triggers the `_critical` method code branch, which results in my seeing the error.

When I dive deeper, it looks like Magento pulls the allowed attributes with the following code

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource/Acl/Filter/Attribute.php
public function getAllowedAttributes($userType, $resourceId, $operation)
{
    $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable(), 'allowed_attributes')
        ->where('user_type = ?', $userType)
        ->where('resource_id = ?', $resourceId)
        ->where('operation = ?', $operation);
    Mage::Log((string) $select);
    return $this->getReadConnection()->fetchOne($select);
}
```

In plain SQL, that's

```
SELECT `api2_acl_attribute`.`allowed_attributes` 
FROM `api2_acl_attribute` 
WHERE (user_type = 'admin') 
    AND (resource_id = 'product') AND (operation = 'write');
```

When I look at my `api2_acl_attribute` table, it's empty

[image]

What's supposed to populate this table with data?  Possibly higher level,  what key bit of setup/usage/received-wisdom have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]:

In Magento's REST implementation, we have two logical possible actions on each resource’s attributes :

- Read action
- Write action

Each REST resource can have own attributes and depending on api2.xml configuration for specific resource, for each REST role, 
we can allow read/write operation for each specific attribute.

To make is simpler to understand:

**Example:**

Customer address is Resource.

Customer address has attributes:

Street
City
ZIP
Country

In Customer Address extension’s api2.xml file could be defined available options depending on user type like this:

- Admin user has option to read and write attributes: Street, City, ZIP and Country from Customer Address resource.
- Customer has options to read attributes Street, City, ZIP and Country from Customer Address resource.
- Guest has option to read only Street attribute from customer address etc.

This options depending for each role (Administrator, Customer, Guest) will appear in Magento admin area under Attributes configuration screen for specific role and administrator needs to check the attributes and operations (read, write) that he wants to allow on specific resource:

[image: REST Attributes]

I wrote three articles about REST web services in Magento and I hope that you will find them useful. Also your question is answered in first one:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento-rest-and-oauth-intro/
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/

Comment: There is also an example on how to consume Magento's REST with Zend OAuth Consumer: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/

Comment: Posting just a link is not a good practice. The answer is supposed to have an actual answer and then if you want you can add some links for further reading.

Answer (score 4):

Per [the internets](https://twitter.com/schumacherfm/status/440972769501515777), these values are generated via the

```
System -> Web Services -> Rest Attributes
```

section of the admin.